# Postgres similarity (or text search) matching partial document

Tags: postgresql, pg-trgm

Call me an amateur full-text search dev, here... I've read some tutorials, but now hit a bit of a wall. The following uses Postgres's [`pg_trgm` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html):

```
=> select similarity('Foo', 'Foo Bar');
 similarity 
------------
        0.5
```

If `'Foo Bar'` were a document, it would be a perfect match for the `'Foo'` search request. (Yet, it only scores 0.5, let's "live with that" for the moment.) People may argue for using text search instead: `select ts_rank(to_tsvector('Foo Bar'), to_tsquery('Foo'));`. But text search does not support fuzzy search (or so I've read). So the following would score flat-out **zero** in text search, but is possible with `similarity`:

```
=> select similarity('Foo', 'Foot Bar');
 similarity 
------------
        0.3
```

0.3 seems to be a fine degradation of the rank/score, based on the "`t`"ypo in question. **However**, as the document grows in size, these numbers just don't seem to work anymore:

```
=> select similarity('Foo', 'Foo Bar Ball Bob Beast Baby Boy'), similarity('Foo', 'Foot Bar');
 similarity | similarity 
------------+------------
 0.16666667 |        0.3
```

Intuitively, I think the `'Foo Bar Ball...'` document is a better match for the `'Foo'` search request than the `'Foot Bar'` document, but the rank/score does not support this.

So, how does one effectively get the ranking/scoring powers across larger documents, that I think text search provides, while getting the fuzziness that `similarity` provides?

Comment: Did you look at word_similarity or strict_word_similarity?

Comment: Yes, but `word_similarity` seems to only solve for the simple case where the string of the search request appears in the document in that exact order. So it'd match `Foo` against `Foo Bar Ball`, it would also match `Foo Bar` against `Foo Bar Ball`, but it *wouldn't* match `Foo Ball` against `Foo Bar Ball`.